# Page refreshes automatically onClick

Tags: javascript, forms, button, onclick, onsubmit

hello 
i have a webpage that refreshes automatically when user clicks the "Calculate button" which calls a javascript function. There is a onLoad event in the body tag. I also use a bit of jquery.
http://gist.github.com/644498

Comment: Jeez, think before you post a "question" people :) Get your thoughts together.

Comment: Have you tried: return false; after you call to your button: `onClick="calculatePayment();return false;"`

Answer (score 14):

Having `form` tags around your buttons would cause the page to refresh. I was dealing with the same problem and it took me all day to fix it. Putting `;return false;` after the function name works great if there's no way you can go without the form tags.

**Example:**

`<button onclick="send(form);return false;"> Send </button>`

Comment: Thank you! I've been banging my head on the wall for a while now, this solved my problem : )

Answer (score 0):

You could use event.preventDefault() just below function name. This prevents the default action that belongs to the event, in this case being the page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

If the javascript function is being called using "onClick" and inside form:form tag , then you need to append "return false" after the fn call.

E.g.`onclick="resetForm();return false;"`